# How to Get Response String from HTTP Server using HTTPSRedirect.h (NodeMCU)

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

The following code is responible for getting a string from HTTP Server

```
while (client.connected())
  {
      if (client.available())
        {
            String line = client.printRedir(url3, host);
            Serial.println(line); 
        }
  }`
```

Error Message:

> no matching function for call to 'HTTPSRedirect::printRedir(String&,
>   const char*&)

How to store the response string from server

Answer (score 1):

The use of HTTPSRedirect library makes the task much simpler by avoiding the need of any third party service. So, the first thing you need to do is to copy the HTTPSRedirect library files from GitHub and install into your Arduino libraries folder. I have also posted the zipped library files at the following link for convenience.

Download HTTPSRedirect Library
Update: **The above library is outdated.**
Please go to GitHub Sujay Phadke and download the updated library. Thanks Sujay.

from above discussion it must be you are using old version of HTTPSRedirect library,
to get new got to [[Updated Library ]](https://github.com/electronicsguy/ESP8266/tree/electronicsguy-patch-29) and download the library and copy the HTTPSRedirect folder from zip folder into the Arduino Ide libraries.
the above process solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Define the host as below

```
const char* host = "your host";
```

And for string use

```
String url = "your complete url";
```